# Set the property value from XML View

Tags: xml, sapui5

i want to write a custom control in UI5

i followed the example [Example Custom Control(Rating)](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw75/helpdata/en/d1/2d2ee6a5454d799358d425f9e7c4db/content.htm)

in the example where we are using the custom control in webapp/view/Detail.view.xml

as

```
<wt:ProductRating class="sapUiSmallMarginBeginEnd" change="onRatingChange"/>
```

we are not setting the value property so default it is taking 0

how can i set the property from the xml like

```
<wt:ProductRating class="sapUiSmallMarginBeginEnd" change="onRatingChange" **value="4"**/>
```

Comment: if you have defined a property `value` in your custom control's `metadata`, then you already have the correct way of setting it from XML view

Comment: if you are setting a value anyhow then better stripoff default value. And make sure you have this `metadata : {
   properties : {
    value:  {type : "float", defaultValue : 0}
   },`  in your custom control code.